# Gekko optimisation error with a nonlinear function and 2 inputs

Tags: python, nonlinear-optimization, gekko

I want to maximise a concave function with two inputs

max 2 * x1 ** .8 + 1.4 * x2 ** .9

st x1 + x2 == C

using Gekko, but I get a error code -2.

```
 
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO()

C = m.Param(value=10)

x1, x2 = [m.Var(lb=0, ub=10) for i in range(2)]

x1.value = 5
x2.value = 5

m.Equation(x1 + x2 == C)

m.Obj(2 * x1 ** .8 + 1.4 * x2 ** .9)

m.options.IMODE = 3

m.solve()

print(x1.value)
print(x2.value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a successful solution by switching to the APOPT solver `m.options.SOLVER = 1`. In this case the default solver, IPOPT, fails to find a solution but APOPT succeeds.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
x1, x2 = m.Array(m.Var,2,value=5,lb=0,ub=10)
m.Equation(x1+x2 == 10)
m.Minimize(2 * x1 ** .8 + 1.4 * x2 ** .9)

m.options.IMODE = 3
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve()

print(x1.value)
print(x2.value)
```

[image: contour plot]

A contour plot with the solution shows that it did reach the optimal value along the black line (x1+x2=10 constraint).

```py
# Generate a contour plot
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Design variables at mesh points
xg = np.arange(0.0, 10.0, 0.1)
yg = np.arange(0.0, 10.0, 0.1)
x1g,x2g = np.meshgrid(xg, yg)

# Equation / Constraint
eq1 = x1g+x2g

# Objective
obj = 2*x1g**0.8 + 1.4*x2g**0.9

# Create a contour plot
plt.figure()
# Objective
CS = plt.contour(x1g,x2g,obj)
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
# Equation
CS = plt.contour(x1g,x2g,eq1,[10.0],colors='k',linewidths=[4.0])
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
# Plot optimal point
plt.plot(x1.value[0],x2.value[0],'o',color='orange',markersize=10)
plt.xlabel('x1'); plt.ylabel('x2')
plt.savefig('contour.png')
plt.show()
```

The orange dot is the optimal solution at `x1=0` and `x2=10`.

**Edit: Maximize instead of Minimize**

The problem statement is Maximize instead of Minimize. Thanks for the correction.

[image: Maximize Objective]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
x1, x2 = m.Array(m.Var,2,value=5,lb=0,ub=10)
m.Equation(x1+x2 == 10)
m.Maximize(2 * x1 ** .8 + 1.4 * x2 ** .9)

m.options.IMODE = 3
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve()

print(x1.value)
print(x2.value)

# Generate a contour plot
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Design variables at mesh points
xg = np.arange(0.0, 10.0, 0.1)
yg = np.arange(0.0, 10.0, 0.1)
x1g,x2g = np.meshgrid(xg, yg)

# Equation / Constraint
eq1 = x1g+x2g

# Objective
obj = 2*x1g**0.8 + 1.4*x2g**0.9

# Create a contour plot
plt.figure()
# Objective
CS = plt.contour(x1g,x2g,obj)
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
# Equation
CS = plt.contour(x1g,x2g,eq1,[10.0],colors='k',linewidths=[4.0])
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
# Plot optimal point
plt.plot(x1.value[0],x2.value[0],'o',color='orange',markersize=10)
plt.xlabel('x1'); plt.ylabel('x2')
plt.savefig('contour.png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: That's interesting, I don't think the edge solution is the right one, there is a better one fun: 13.264488129859771, x: array([6.32660461, 3.67339539])

Comment: Ah I got it now, you need to swap minimize for maximize in your version

Comment: Thanks - I'll add that solution too.